# Elastic length filter

Tags: elasticsearch

I am trying to take advantage of the `length` filter in ElasticSearch

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-length-tokenfilter.html

In the example provided, it simply removes the matching tokens.

But when I use it, it replaces the tokens with `_`

Anyone ran in to this problem?

I suppose I can add a character filter. But maybe there is some undocumented feature?

Example:

String `i eat icecream`

If I apply `length` filter, with `min = 3, max=10`, the tokens I get, is:

`_ eat icecream` instead of `eat icecream`

Comment: can you please explain your issue with the help of an example ?

Comment: I edited answer with example

Answer (score 0):

Using your string `"i eat icecream"` and analyzing it using a length token filter, I am getting the below result (tested on Elasticsearch version 7.x)

```
GET /_analyze
{
  "tokenizer": "whitespace",
  "filter": [
    {
      "type": "length",
      "min": 3,
      "max": 10
    }
  ],
  "text": "i eat icecream"
}
```

The tokens generated are

```
{
  "tokens": [
    {
      "token": "eat",
      "start_offset": 2,
      "end_offset": 5,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 1
    },
    {
      "token": "icecream",
      "start_offset": 6,
      "end_offset": 14,
      "type": "word",
      "position": 2
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: @galdikas which version of elasticsearch are you using ? Can you please share your index mapping ?